# Bash Script: Test vs. if issues

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a simple script to check the current nice level of a process.

The following works without any issues:

```
test "$(ps axl | grep '[m]y_process' | awk '{print $6}')" != '-10' && (echo test)
```

However, I do more than just a simple echo and I was hoping to break this up into an if statement.  That being said, using the exact same test, it fails everytime.  Here's the code:

```
if [ "$(ps axl | grep '[m]y_process' | awk '{print $6}')" != '-10' ];
  then
    echo "test"
    # other stuff goes here
fi
```

As a result, I'm sure there's something wrong with my syntax.  I've also tried using the -ne comparison and using double quotes for the nice level (e.g., -10).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edited to add:

When I just try running:

```
ps axl | grep '[m]y_process' | awk '{print $6}'
```

from a script, it returns a blank string instead of the process nice level, so I've narrowed it down to this...

Edited to add 2:

The test command was only run from the console, so the syntax may/may not work from a script...

Comment: Your code doesn't fail for me. It echos "test" to the console as expected.

Comment: Why are you using square brackets here: `grep '[m]y_process'`?

Comment: When you say "it fails everytime", what exactly does happen?

Comment: @anubhava, that's a way to match "my_process" processes without matching the grep process -- that regex will match the string "my_process" but it will not match the string "[m]y_process"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a FAQ. `if` statements process the exit status of UNIX commands, including the `test` command. Just use the natural exit status of the commands you're trying to process instead of trying to test the string output of a capturing expression inside `test`. For example:

```
if ps axl | awk '/[m]y_process/{ if ($6 == -10) { exit 1 } else { exit 0 } }' …
```

Comment: See my question again.  I'd rather have it broken up into multiple lines and don't want to exit in the case where the if statement catches the case...

Comment: Also, can you please help me understand why the I can't run the command from the script, but I can from the console?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard.  I found the issue.  Instead of doing a grep in my script, I had typed pgrep.  This is why I hate being the only software guy on my project.

:(

Comment: You can delete the question :)